# Traffic manager with multiple endpoints in same location

Tags: azure, web, traffic, azure-traffic-manager

I'm trying to add web app endpoints from the same location, to an azure traffic manager, when I try to do this, it tells me that App Service will use load balancing to do this for me, when we apps are in the same location.

My understanding is that load balancing is for distributing requests between multiple VMs on **one** web app. The plan was to use out single DNS and allow traffic manager to determine which endpoint to go to using round-robin or failover. How will load balancing know to direct to one of the web apps from this single address?

Comment: please mark as answer if correct.

Answer (score 4):

Azure Web Apps already have built in load balancing between instances within the web app.  So for example if you have a web app with 10 instances under the endpoint: tester.azurewebsites.net, Azure load balances appropriately across those instances.

When you bring in traffic manager, that is looking for different endpoints to facilitate between.  Incoming requests will be routed based on proximity to endpoints it is managing, load and if the endpoint is available.  Traffic Manager takes care of all of those complexities for you.

This allows you to have a single endpoint myapp.azurewebsites.net; which may route to myapp-west.azurewebsites.net and myapp-east.azurewebsites.net.  That routing as I indicated is based on proximity, load and availability.

How it actually works is the magic sauce of Azure Traffic Manager.  I use it in production and it has been working very well for me.  I primarily use it for routing based on proximity, and have yet to experience a failure on a web app to test a production failover reroute.

Hope that helps!